# Network Adapter NUMA

Tags: c++, windows, networking, numa

Is there any way in a windows system, to (a) programmatically find the NUMA node of a network adapter without writing a driver or (b) read and write the Receive Side Scaling option for a network adapter without writing a driver?

The best solution would be (a) so the configuration could be setup completely automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/09/13/getting-system-topology-information-on-windows.aspx) details how to get the topology information about the different resources in the system, including how to find the NUMA node of any device in the system.  Basically, a program walks the device tree until an entity (such as a PCI bus) is found that is associated with a NUMA node.

(disclaimer: I wrote the post while I worked at Microsoft)

Comment: Well yes i can find the PCI Bus of the network adapter. But i do not know the NUMA node or CPU of this bus

Comment: The immediate bus (or any bus between your device and the root) should have DEVPKEY_Numa_Proximity_Domain key set.  If this key is not set, then the BIOS / ACPI has not exposed the required information to the OS.

If the key is set, then you can convert the proximity domain to the NUMA node (they are equivalent).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that on monday